# How to get the count of number of commits of a specific branch?

Tags: git, git-commit

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to get the count of the number of commits done on a specific branch.

I have tried using `rev-list`, but the count I am getting is different.

```
PS C:\Dev\code\TestProj> git checkout master
Already on 'master'                            
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
PS C:\Dev\code\TestProj> git checkout -B "TESTBRANCH"
Switched to a new branch 'TESTBRANCH'
PS C:\Dev\code\TestProj> git commit -a -m "TESTBRANCH-TEST COMMIT"
[TESTBRANCH 3a98967] TESTBRANCH-TEST COMMIT
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)            
PS C:\Dev\code\TestProj> git rev-list --count --first-parent TESTBRANCH
9
PS C:\Dev\code\TestProj>
```

In the above code, I have made only one commit on the new branch which I created and I can see the count returned is 9. I think Git is taking into consideration some other revisions as well.

Is there a way to get the commit count as just 1?

Comment: How specific do you need? Git doesn't keep a proper history of commits on a branch, since branches are temporary and change a lot

Comment: Your `git rev-list` exploration will by default go back to the initial commit. If you want to limit ancestry, you'll have to tell git that (for example, with [`--not`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---not)).

Comment: @evolutionxbox even if its not for the count, i need to atleast get if the branch has the commits. having said that if i create a new branch and without any commits check the branch to see if there is any commits then it should return false . Hope this clarifies..

Comment: If you create a new branch on a commit, and that commit as ancestors, the count will always be greater than 1

Comment: Where does the branch start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you'll want to use a commit range from master to TESTBRANCH. This will count all commits made on TESTBRANCH since it diverged from master:

```sh
git rev-list --count --first-parent master..TESTBRANCH
```

The answer to this should be 1.

If you pull later, and there are new commits on master, you can also count the number of commits since TESTBRANCH was created just by flipping the order of the arguments in the range:

```sh
git rev-list --count --first-parent TESTBRANCH..master
```

This syntax, of `<branch A>..<branch B>`, is called a commit range. For a more in-depth explanation, see [this article on commit ranges,](https://darekkay.com/blog/git-commit-ranges/) although a short summary would be:

`<branch A>..<branch B>` refers to all the commits on branch B, that aren't on branch A. So `master..TESTBRANCH` means "all the commits on TESTBRANCH, that aren't on master".

Comment: Thanks Alecto. this answers more appropriately with better explanation. making this as an accepted Answer

Comment: This assumes the parent branch name, which might not always be desired

Answer (score 1):

Your `rev-list` will just walk all the way to the very first commit. If `TESTBRANCH` is branched from `main`, you can try:

```
git log --oneline TESTBRANCH ^main
```